# What is the difference between CreateCompatibleRenderTarget and CreateHwndRenderTarget

Tags: c++, direct2d

I am just confused about the difference since, we can just make a bitmap the size of the window and then draw the image onto the window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is in the name: [CreateCompatibleRenderTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371825%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does just that in that it creates a render target that is compatible with the current display settings. [CreateHwndRenderTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371279%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) conversely creates a RT that simply renders to a window. So it is not set up the same way as the compatible target.

[What is a render target?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb976073%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx)

Even though that talks about XNA, most of the primitive information there is agnostic of even DirectX and simply discusses the idea of a render target.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense. However, what does it mean when you say "creates a render target"?

Comment: Creating a render target means allocating an object that has the properties of a render target and is usually in a reserved section of memory space so it can be moved to the GPU. DirectX (COM) allocations are unique compared to your everyday 'new'. And a render target is simply data that represents pixel data and can be pushed onto a device. See my updates.